# Landscape Openstack not showing utilisation

Tags: openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I have an openstack environment setup (deployed with autopilot) that I've been testing, and while everything is working perfectly fine, my landscape server is reporting no utilization.  All of the 15 servers are reporting fine.

I'm at a loss as to where the log file I should be looking for is located in effort to find the issue.

I've tried to restart all of the servers and services in a systematic order, however, it still is showing nothing.

[image: Landscape (openstack tab)]

Comment: How are you using the cloud? What parts do you think are not being correctly reported as used? The screen grabs you shared indicate light usage.

Comment: Actually, it reports light usage for 8 days, then the meters stopped reporting, and when they are highlighted, it shows 0% of 0 available.  I've actually have redeployed.  I can't test the answers given.  @AdamCollard

Answer (score 0):

I cant answer to what is wrong. But to get you into where you could find out.

On your MAAS server do `export JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/juju`

Then

```
juju ssh landscape-server/0 sudo 'JUJU_HOME=/var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/`sudo ls -rt /var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/ | tail -1` sudo -u landscape -E bash'
```

if you then run `juju status` you should see the states and location of all the parts of your cloud.